# Summarising twice in same pipe R

Tags: r, dplyr

I obviously get an error with the below but I was hoping to summarise the same column with regards to mean and median, and also how many points are in the polygon. But within the same pipe. Any help would be great.

```
Nin_Sep_points_sf_joined <- 
  st_join(merged_ten_seven_shp, Nin_Sep_sf_3011) %>%  
  filter(!is.na(Employment_diff)) %>% 
  group_by(Kod) %>%
  summarise(Count=mean(as.numeric(as.character(price)))), summarise(Count_tot=n()),  summarise(Count=median(as.numeric(as.character(price))))
```

Comment: Can you put the current error log msg?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can supply multiple arguments to `summarize` which you separate with a `,`:

```
library(dplyr)
Nin_Sep_points_sf_joined <- 
  st_join(merged_ten_seven_shp, Nin_Sep_sf_3011) %>%  
  filter(!is.na(Employment_diff)) %>% 
  group_by(Kod) %>%
  summarise(Count=mean(as.numeric(as.character(price))),
            Count_tot=n(),
            Count=median(as.numeric(as.character(price))))
```

Note that you can even refer to the results of previous arguments in the next argument. So you could calculate SD based on `Count_tot`.